# MariaDB, TLS and localhost connection

Tags: ssl, mariadb

I have a CentOS 8 with MariaDB (10.3.17).
The server is setup with TLS and I have configured the server to use 2-Way TLS, following the MariaDB examples: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/#enabling-one-way-tls-for-mariadb-clients

However, I cannot make the 2-Way TLS to work when I use the `localhost` connection.

So, what I have:

`mariadb-server`

```
port = 3306
ssl_cert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/dbsrv.example.com_crt.pem
ssl_key = /etc/pki/tls/private/dbsrv.example.com_key.pem
ssl_ca  = /etc/pki/tls/certs/dbsrv.example.com_chain.pem
ssl-cipher = kEECDH:+kEECDH+SHA:kEDH:+kEDH+SHA:+kEDH+CAMELLIA:kECDH:+kECDH+SHA:kRSA:+kRSA+SHA:+kRSA+CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!SSLv2:!RC4:!DES:!EXP:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES
```

On the client I have this:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
ssl_cert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/dbsrv.example.com_crt.pem
ssl_key = /etc/pki/tls/private/dbsrv.example.com_key.pem
ssl_ca = /etc/pki/tls/certs/dbsrv.example.com_chain.pem
ssl-verify-server-cert = true
```

The `_chain` certificates have the Intermediate certificate (whichi signed the _crt files) and the CA certificate. The CA certificate is added to the host's trust store (although it's not used from mariadb as far as I understand)

The CN of the certificates are:

```
subject=C ... CN = dbsrv.example.com, ...
subject=C ... CN = jumphost.example.com, ...
subject=C ... CN = MyCA-Int, ...
```

Now the problem.

When I connect with localhost I get this error message:

```sh
mysql  -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Validation of SSL server certificate failed
```

But if I connect though TCP, it works:

```
mysql -h dbsrv.example.com -u root -p      
Enter password:
```

```sql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 30
Server version: 10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          30
Current database:
Current user:           root@dbsrv.example.com
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             dbsrv.example.com via TCP/IP
...
```

If I remove the `ssl-verify-server-cert = true` from the client configuration it works as well, but it's not what I want.

```sh
mysql  -u root -p              
Enter password:
```

````sql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 31
Server version: 10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          31
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket

----------------------------

```bash
mysql -h dbsrv.example.com -u root -p
Enter password:
````

```sql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 32
Server version: 10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          32
Current database:
Current user:           root@dbsrv.example.com
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.3.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             dbsrv.example.com via TCP/IP
```

So, how can I make it work with the `localhost` connection as well?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a relation between certificates and domain names.  So, it might be hard to obtain a certificate for "localhost".  Why would you want SSL for a local connection?  Do you fear a "man in the middle" attack?

Comment: No, I simply don't want to change the current trend. DBAs connect with `mysql -u -p ` and they are not very adamant to use the -h FQDN. 

And at the same time I need 2-Way verification due to the security policy. So, I need to find a way to make it work with both, without using any nasty aliases.

Comment: I think you mean your DBAs are "very adamant not to use  the -h FQDN".  Having been a DBA for a number of decades myself, I fully understand they are hard to work with.  What about putting the FQDN in /etc/my.cnf?  Just in case nobody can tell you how to use SSL with localhost.

Comment: I didn't think this. Probably a good solution.

(ps yes, not was meant to be there :) )

Comment: LOL. "No, I simply don't want to change the current trend."  Not only adamant DBA's, I see.

Comment: So, it could be possible after all.  What do you think of this: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/ ?

Comment: I am close to this.  
Since I have control on the CA, I might use the localhost as an SAN and see if it works. If does, I will use it. Otherwise, I will have one more discussion with the DBA. Besides, we have to use TLS and there is no exception on this...

Comment: I am very curious to know what the benefits could be in using an encrypted local connection.  You are aware of the performance cost?

Comment: Personally, I cannot see **any** benefit on this. Not even in the 2-Way verification. 
I can limit the access to the mysql port via the machine or network firewall. 
The security team seems not to understand the term "local', or there is something else I completely miss! 

Regarding the performance cost, it's not that high, the server is on 15-25% CPU utilization and in terms of performance looks OK, at least for now.

Comment: The loss of performance will only be apparent when a DBA needs to do a large transfer of information to or from the DB.  For instance, a backup.  Keep this in mind.  Protecting (which this is NOT) yourself against one of your DBA's ????   Is your "security" team qualified?

Comment: Let's just say that they are a bit paranoid... 
In the meantime I prepare a different solution. I talked with the DBAs and they agree that we can limit the TLS connections to very specific users and very specific hosts. 
We don't have '%' anyehere in the permissions, so, we might end up with a solution that will enable 2-Way TLS only for remote connections and only for root. Which makes more sense. So, now time will be spent on preparing a presentation for the obvious.